# How to make dragons crash land?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

How to make a dragon fail landing/crash on the ground/fall from the sky ?

I don't mean Dragonrend.

I mean when a dragon falls from the sky and land badly, in a way they stop attacking for some seconds while they recover, when this happens, they usually make changes on the land around them, though, you can actually walk through the dirt the crash landing makes.

Example of crash landing:

How do I make this happen?

I've heard that shooting them in the wings may cause this, or does this just happen when it's on low health and in the air?

What actually triggers the crash landing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just need to [do a bit of damage.](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Dragon#Combat)

> Once the dragon has been injured to a certain extent, usually after half of its health has dropped, it will remain grounded.

Comment: I think what you quoted means they will stop flying, not crash-land, or not ?

Comment: @Ramirez It has been my experience that those are one and the same. I've never had a dragon *not* crash land.

Comment: Ok, so arrow in the wing while a dragon is on full health doesn't trigger this? :(

Comment: @Ramirez - Nope.  Just their overall health.

Comment: @fluttershy I have never seen a dragon crash land, except for that one time mission where you see one awaken another.

Answer (score 0):

All you gotta do is shoot them while they're flying around, not stationary otherwise it'll just drop. Get it to half health while it's flying around and you'll make it land that way

Comment: Hi, BC. This doesn't really add anything to the accepted answer. Please go through the other answers to see if your answer's already there. And please take our [Tour] to familiarize yourself with our platform. Welcome!

Answer (score -4):

Get into an open area where there aren't many structures around, and then he will just land on his own.

Comment: Do you mean to say dragons are so inept at flying they will crash without any interference from the player? I find that hard to believe.